# (New) Google Sites - Auto Page navigation

Tags: load, auto, sites

I need to automate page loading for google sites (the new version).

I've built a handful (6) of pages that serve as a display/info screen. Each page has different content to view.

Previously I had hosted site and I'd move away from this as the hosting cost is no longer appropriate. For that I used the following meta tag:

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="200;my-site-url-here">`

That solution worked fine, but I dont seem able to get this working in Google Sites.

Do any of you smart people know of a work around that will auto load the next page in my Google Site after a set amount of time?

Any help appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know this answer as well, for the moment I'm Opening the pages under a new tab, have two tabs open then use tab switcher add on to automatically switch between the two. It works for the time being. If I could I'd like it to transition between the pages smoothly or fade, but can't seem to do it with Google sites.